# axis 1.4 jar not getting added in Mule Project

Tags: mule, axis, pom.xml

I have a Mule 3.4.0 project which has a dependency to axis 1.4 jar file. 
I have added this as a dependency in POM file, but it is not getting added to "Referenced Libraries" section. This jar file is available in the maven repository.

What could be the issue?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId> 
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId> 
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Other dependencies like "axis-jaxrpc" and "axis-saaj" jars get added without any issue from the same group Id.

Comment: Are you using Anypoint Studio 3.5? What do you get when running `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: I am using 3.5.0 Mule Studio. I don't see any error. I changed the artifactId to axis_main.. now it got added (looks like there is an exclusion for axis in Mule POM)

Comment: You are right, it is excluded in the Mule root pom.